# When should we call getContext and getActivity once and for all?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

*I searched a lot on StackOverflow and more generally on Google for explanations about the use of contexts in the Android environment, but I only found scattered fragments of explanations.*

When should we use `getContext` instead of `getActivity`? **The question is precised below.**

- **Within a `DialogFragment`, and other `Fragment`**: creating a `Toast`, building an `AlertDialog`,instanciating an `Intent`... require a context. Should we use `getActivity` or `getContext`?
- **And if these operations are written in an `Activity`** instead of a fragment?

By the way, a Null exception and/or memory leaks can occur by calling `getContext` and `getActivity`: when? More precisely: does it occur only when the lifetime of the caller is a (strict) subset of the lifetime of the called object (for example, a `Dialog` calls `getActivity/getContext` which returns null if it's not yet attached to its activity)?

Comment: I don't actually have a problem, I just don't understand how it is possible to not have any definitive resource about when precisely calling the right method of both. It should be extremely clear and I didn't find a definitive answer. Someone tells to use getActivity for UI widgets but why? There isn't any documentation speaking about it. By the way, a lot of Stackoverflow answers recommend to use class/objects attributes to store the context and the activity from the OnAttach callback. However, other say that it is a bad think which can rise a memory leak. How is it possible in 2019 to have..

Comment: ... To have a lot of contradictions about getContext and getActivity? This question is intended to clear all these weird answers and myths.

Comment: Other incertitudes are for example: getActivity and getContext are the same word, one said. But obviously it's not true. This question should also clear these incertitudes. In fact it could bring a definitive and complete answer to all these misunderstandings about getContext and getActivity. We are in 2019, how is it possible to be so unprecise about using getContext and getActivity... All my questions should have been treated in the official documentation and/or in Stackoverflow questions... But no... In 2019...

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this kind of question is quite important for well understanding what we do as developpers...It is not always "Hey guys help help help, I have a bug, here is my code", but also "How can I do this in the most beautiful way ?"  ... This question (and its answer) was helpful for me, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), The Context object contains global information about an application environment. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

the `getContext()` method returns the context associated with the current object, which may be a View, or a Fragment or Dialog or any other object that has this method defined in it or inherits it.

the `getActivity()` method returns a reference to the current activity associated with a Fragment object. If there is no activity associated with the fragment it WILL return `null`. I personally never use this method when passing a context argument, I only use `getContext()` and `getApplicationContext()`.

`getApplicationContext()` is especially useful because it uses a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, it is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component. Which means it uses the context of the App instead of that of part of the app, like an activity. [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext())

Context Best Practices:

- `getContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` are sufficient for passing a context argument. If they are not accessible immediately you can use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` chaining to pass appropriate context argument. This means you can use this to create `Toasts`, `AlertDialogs`, `Intents`, `Fragments` and other view manipulations that require context.
- Never assign a context to a static (class) variable, It will create a memory leak!
- If you use `getApplicationContext()` to register broadcasts you must perform the appropriate clean-up to prevent memory leaks. [see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#java)

*Note that these are my personal approaches, I stand to be corrected :).*

Comment: @Edgar- We should use getApplicationContext() very careful(should avoid in most cases), for example if we try to inflate a layout using getApplicationContext() While the framework will not complain and will return a perfectly good view hierarchy from a LayoutInflater created with the application context, the themes and styles from your app will not be considered in the process. So we should try to use activity/service context as much possible